# Print Report without ReportViewer in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, printing, reportviewer, business-intelligence

I am using Business Intelligent reporting servicess to reporting some data from My MS SQL Database. In ASP.NET I create new Reporting Viewer that take data from BI and display the report then I can Print it.

My Question is How can I print the report without report viewer?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

I tend to deliver reports optimized for printing as .pdf responses. This assumes the client has a .pdf reader installed. Since you scenario sounds like a business focused one, this might be reasonable.

If the report server is directly accessible, you can access the report via the report's url (something like this...):

```
"http://myserver/reportserver?/MyReports/MyPrintFriendlyReport&rs:Command=Render&rc:LinkTarget=main&rs:Format=PDF"
```

I don't usually get to do this. To overcome secure access/firewall issues, I create a page to call the reporting services web service. The render method returns a byte array based on the parameters you provide ("pdf" if you specify). Then you modify the content-type headers and Response.BinaryWrite the result.

You should be able to google for sample code for this (I have none accessible right now).